# React Native NFC Card Reader For IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, nfc, payment

I am trying to do a project using NFC. I am trying to make an app so that when you hold apple pay to the NFC from the app it should show the card details. (This is not for stealing or anything.). I found a library however, it does not support IOS. I am trying to find a library that will allow so that when I open the NFC tag from the app and someone holds their Apple Pay it should get the card information. I could't find a library that supports IOS. There are NFC scanners out there but they do not work with cards. Can anyone help me with this.

(This project is not to steal any card information. I am trying to make an app like a credit card processor similar to Square.)

Comment: iOS apps cannot (currently) read credit card details. [Tap to Pay](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2022/02/apple-unveils-contactless-payments-via-tap-to-pay-on-iphone/) will be available in the US later this year through selected payment processors.

Comment: Even with Tap to Pay, however, the app will not receive any payment card details. They will be passed securely to the payment processor